# Filter multiple custom fields Values with Check boxes

Tags: custom-field, filters

I create check boxes with name of custom field value. Here is 2 custom fields and every field have 2 type of values.

need to show filter result of selected boxes??

every custom field have two type of values. brand key values [ Apple or Nokia ] and Price key values [ 100$ or 200$ ]

**Custom Fields**

```
  <?php  get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'brand', true ); ?>
  <?php  get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'price', true ); ?>
```

**how to filter these 4 checkbox**

```
  Brand:
  <input name="nokia" id="nokia" type="checkbox" /> Nokia <br>
  <input name="apple" id="apple" type="checkbox" /> Apple <br>        
  Price:
  <input name="price1" id="price1" type="checkbox" /> 100$ <br>
  <input name="price2" id="price2" type="checkbox" /> 200$ <br>
```